# ConTeXt: How to align a delimitedtext?

Tags: context

I'm using pandoc's default `ConTeXt` template, and it uses the following setup for `blockquotes`:

```
\setupdelimitedtext
  [blockquote]
  [before={\blank[medium]},
   after={\blank[medium]},
   indentnext=no,
   align=middle
  ]
```

Then, any quoted text is entered as

```
\startblockquote
 Quoted text
\stopblockquote
```

Now I want to have this quoted text centered on the page, but `setupdelimitedtext` does not seem to have that option (adding `align=middle` has no effect).

This surprises me, as it seems like a reasonable expectation, and makes me suspicious that perhaps I'm going about it all wrong. Is there a more *ConTeXt-idiomatic* way to do this?

Also, I can't find documentation for the `setupdelimitedtext` command in the `ConTeXt` manual. Is it been deprecated or something?

Comment: delimitedtext does not provide the `align` key. (Even if it did, you need a comma after `align=middle` to get it to work). If you need a specific feature of delimitedtext, please send a feature request to the context mailing list to add `align` key to delimitedtext? If you just need middle alignment, then the following works: `\definestartstop[blockquote][before={\blank[medium]\startmiddlealigned},after={\stopmiddlealigned\blank[medium]}]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does align the text in the middle, but doesn't apply line breaks, so only a small fraction of my text is displayed. Inserting `\crlf` doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the alignment in a delimited text environment with the setup `before={\setupalign[middle]}`. What can be changed as well is to set the spacing around the environment with the `spacebefore` and `spaceafter` keys, the setting for `spaceafter` is only needed when you want a different value from `spacebefore`.

```
\setupdelimitedtext
  [blockquote]
  [spacebefore=medium,
   %spaceafter=medium,
   indentnext=no,
   before={\setupalign[middle]}]

\starttext

\input knuth

\startblockquote
\input ward
\stopblockquote 

\input zapf

\stoptext
```

Comment: This works as well, and seems the most succinct, but I wonder if this is idiomatic, to use `\setupalign` in the middle of the document like that?

Is the choice between `before=\setupalign[middle]` and `before=\startalignment[middle], after=\stopalignment` purely personal preference or are there some guidelines or issues I'm not aware of?

The spacing issue is incidental, but thanks anyway for the tip :-)

Comment: The `\startalignment` is a simple wrapper for the `\setupalign` command which starts a group before the alignment is changed to keep the changes local to the group. Because the blockquote environment already starts a local group before the `\setupalign` is used there is no need to use the `\startalignment` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Aditya's comment, I've found something that works:

```
\definestartstop[blockquote][before={\blank[medium]\startalignment[middle]},
                             after={\stopalignment\blank[medium]}]
```

It'd be helpful to understand why `\startmiddlealigned` didn't work though...

Comment: \startmiddleanligned...\stopmiddlealigned is equivalent to \midaligned{...}, so it typesets the content inside a \hbox, that does not split lines.

Comment: @mszep you wanted it, centered on the page. And you already said that it works. But I'm not quite sure with the above code, blockquote is centered on the page.

Comment: @doed I should have been more precise; I meant horizontally centered. Indeed, the above code centers the text horizontally, but not vertically, so the text does not necessarily appear in the middle of the page.